# Bitbucket - 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe ls-tree -z -l refs/heads/develop: --' exited with code 0

Tags: server, bitbucket

Bitbucket Data Center shows me this error

[image: screenshot]

I have this problem, as can be seen in the photo.

I can't get it back via backup because unfortunately I can't get the repository ID because as soon as I go to the repo I get this error.

What should I do?

This error occurred after migration to another server. I changed the home path and it works for every repository but this one.

I tried to restore it from backup, but unfortunately I don't see the ID.